# Kindle Keyboard Wont Go To Drive Mode

Tags: kindle

My Kindle Keyboard won't Enter USB Drive Mode and IDK How To Get it too. it is version 3.4.2 B008. pls help me!

Comment: no answer yet? and im 16 hours in?

Comment: The point of STack Exchnage is for good questions and answers that can be referred to in the future and so a day is not a long time. Also this particular site does not have many users so you need to wait longer than elsewhere.

Comment: ah ok. makes sense.